# Is it possible to extract text from PDF from File API on input rather than getting the stored document?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am trying to build a web-based utility that allows a user to 'choose' a system file utilizing `<input type="file">` and immediately extract text data from the file without having to upload the file on to the server. I will then parse the text from the file for multiple applications.

I have come across this method for extracting or scraping text from a PDF file : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript

However, this requires a file be stored and accessed using an HTTP request.

So far I am able to read the PDF file using the File API, but I am not able to interact with the text content.

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="File Upload" id="tpdfFileUpload" accept=".pdf" />
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('pdfFileUpload').addEventListener('change', upload, false);

function upload(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var textData = event.target.result;
        //
        // INSERT Code to convert textData into usable text.
        //  
    };

    reader.onerror = function() {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
    };
}
```

I played around with PDF.js but am having a hard time finding something that would work for this use case.

Comment: I have had the same issue. Have you found a solution ?